# How to make menu output links absolute

Tags: menus, links

The page and post links added to WordPress menus are relative in nature. I need a way to force them to be absolute *without* using the "Custom Link" option.

Is there some function or maybe a modifier that I can use with wp_nav_menu() to accomplish this?

Comment: Huh?  I'm not clear on what you are asking.  Question for you:  On your wp-admin panel, settings, permalinks what setting are you using?  (my recommendation is to use: Post Name)  Does that resolve your problem?  What, exactly what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This sounds like a CSS related problem. In your child theme just modify their classes and add `absolute` value instead of relative (with proper fine tuning).

Comment: The OP is referring to absolute URLs, not absolute positioning. I'm guessing you want them pointing to somewhere other than your site URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes) filter. Using this you should be able to grab the href and modify it as you require.